# R comparison of vector to each row of data table is slow

Tags: r, data.table

I need to compare a range of values (value_range) to values that are in rows of a data table, and then compile the results as sums for each value in value_range.

The METHOD #1 below shows best what I am trying to do. The loop of 10 times is only there to compare the system.time it takes.

```
nb_values = 300
value_range = c(1:nb_values)

nb_rows = 1000
d = data.table( c1 = rep(c(10,30,60,80), (nb_rows/4)) , c2 = rep(2,nb_rows) )

res1 = data.table( rep(0,nb_values) )
res2 = data.table( rep(0,nb_values) )

# METHOD 1
system.time(
    for(i in (1:10))
    {
        for(i in value_range) res1[i] <- d[, sum( (i>c1) & (i>c2) ),]
    }
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  6.973   0.000   6.982 

# METHOD 2
f <- function(i)
{
    d[, sum( (i>c1) & (i>c2) ),]
}

system.time(
    for(i in (1:10))
    {
        res2 <- apply(cbind(value_range), 1, f)
    }
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.152   0.000   3.161 

identical(as.integer(res1$V1), res2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Is there a way to speed this up even further ?

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question using *words*. In particular, you could explain what you are attempting to do with these loops instead of leaving it to us to parse it out.

Comment: It might be me not seeing things, but what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, you have two methods named method 1.... is there meant to be a method 2?

Comment: I'd advise you to use the microbenchmark package for benchmarking.

Comment: Minor point, it is safer to iterate over an iterator, like `i in seq_along(values)` rather than the values themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
system.time(
  for(j in 1:10) {
    res3 <- d[, vapply(value_range, 
                       function(i) sum((i > c1) & (i > c2)), 
                       FUN.VALUE = 1L)]
  })
#user  system elapsed 
#0.15    0.01    0.15 

all.equal(res1$V1, res3)
#[1] TRUE
```